# Non-modal iOS keypad interface

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

Is it known how to get the keypad interface from the Phone and Skype apps? This is distinct from the modal keypad view that appears when a UITextField becomes the first responder.

Is this just a UIView that the developers of Skype laid out themselves in IB, complete with custom graphics to get the square shape of each button? Or is there some standard Cocoa Touch way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that Cocoa Touch provides out of the box, no. I would imagine that the iPhone keypad is a set of `UIButton` objects arranged like a keypad and using custom graphics to get the visual appearance. This should be fairly easy to do in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `UIKeyboardType` in the protocol [`UITextInputTraits`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html), which is implemented by UITextField etc.. See the documentation at that link.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific - I am looking for the keypad view that is NOT modal. Objects like text fields that invoke keypad input do so by having a modal keypad slide up, but the Phone and Skype apps have keypads that are fixed on screen as part of a regular view.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting confused by your question too. I'm not aware of any but seeing as you would need somewhere to type in anyway wouldn't it be better to make the UITextField active on viewWillAppear and turn off touches on the rest of the view hence showing the keypad like the phone app?

Comment: Well, the keypad in the Phone app doesn't slide in the way the UITextField one does - it's just sitting there waiting for you when you navigate to it using the tab bar.